# Find process from executable path

Tags: linux, bash, process

I'd like to be able to find the process id of a given process, knowing the executable path that launched it (which also happens to be it current dir).

The issue is that the sole name of the executable is not enough, as I have multiple process running with the same name.

The only way I can think of is to query each process's working directory, but I wonder if there is a more direct solution.

```sh
for pid in $(pgrep my-program)
do
  if [[ $(pwdx $pid) == $PATH_OF_EXECUTABLE ]]
  then
    echo $pid
    break
  fi
done
```

I should also note that I don't have root permission, and I launched only the process that I am interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found a solution, though it doesn't correspond to my title's requirements. As the user I'm logged into has only launched one instance of the process (the one I'm interested in), I can user `pgrep -u $USER` to filter all other processes.

```sh
$ pgrep -u $USER my-program
12345
```